# Does dpkg -r consider dependence between applications?

Tags: dpkg

When removing an application using `dpkg -r`, how does it handle dependence between installed applications?

If some other installed application depends on the application to be removed, and we still need that application, shall we still run `dpkg -r`?

If we don't want all installed applications depending on the application, shall we still run `dpkg -r`?

Answer (score 1):

No, performing a `-r` or `--remove` does not remove packages that depend on the package being removed. `dpkg` only performs dependency checking, it doesn't do any dependency resolution. If you run `dpkg -r` on a package that other packages depend on, the operation will fail with an error message.

It's best to make use of `apt-get` for package management. `dpkg` should only be reserved for use with listing the contents of a given package/.deb file or for doing the install/removable of packages that are self contained one-offs that do not depend on any other packages.

Comment: Thanks. (1) When a package is created by dpkg -i, will it be able to be used for other applications depending on it? I.e. can it be found, when installing some application depending on it? (2) I installed a new version of emacs by compiling its cource and checkinstall to create a deb package and dpkg -i the package. How do I know if I can safely uninstall my old version of emacs, just to reclaim some free space?

Comment: @Tim - (1) - yes. BTW if you have a .deb file you can use `gdebi mypkg.deb` to install it + its depdencies. (2) - `apt-cache depends <package>`.

Comment: can dpkg uninstall packages installed by apt-get, or do you recommend it?                                                                                    
vice versa?

Comment: `dpkg` can but I would discourage you from using `dpkg` in this manner. If you find that you've made things a mess with `dpkg` you can resolve anything that might be missing with this: `sudo apt-get -f install`.

Comment: can apt-get uninstall packages installed by dpkg? Do you recommend that?

Comment: @Tim - that should be OK.

Comment: " If you find that you've made things a mess with dpkg you can resolve anything that might be missing with this: sudo apt-get -f install". Do you imply that apt-get is aware of all the packages installed by dpkg?

Comment: @Tim - that command will interrogate the system and install what's missing.